# react hooks event handler working different when invoked from button click and keyboard event

Tags: reactjs

This is quite difficult to explain so I have created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v8kvy119wl) to illustrate the problem.

I am working on a package that basically is a wrapper around mousetrap so you can add keyboard events to either the document object or a specific element.

I am testing it out with this code:

```
const boxes = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }].map(
  (b): Box => {
    return { ...b, color: `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)` };
  }
);

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [boxState, setState] = useState(boxes);

  const handleMove = (newPosition: Partial<Point>, index: number) => {
    setState((state) => {
      return state.map((box, i) => {
        return index === i ? { ...box, ...newPosition } : { ...box };
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Click on any box and use arrow keys or WSAD</h1>
      {boxState.map(({ x, y, color }, index) => (
        <MovableBox key={index} color={color} index={index} x={x} y={y} onMoveRequest={handleMove} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the code sandbox, you can move the squares down by either pressing the `D` button in each square of if you click a square, the div gets focus and the arrow keys should move the boxes around.

The problem is that it works fine when pressing the button but when you use the arrow key, the new state is not persisted.  It always starts at it's initial value.

The `Box` component looks like this:

```
export const Box: React.FC<BoxType & BoxProps> = ({ x, y, color, index, onMoveRequest }) => {
  const style: CSSProperties = {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    backgroundColor: color,
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: '100px',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: `${y + index * 120}px`,
    left: `${x + index * 120}px`
  };

  if (index === 0) {
    console.log({ x, y });
  }

  const SHIFT = 10;
  const handleMove = (action) => {
    console.log(index);
    switch (action) {
      case 'MOVE_LEFT':
        onMoveRequest({ x: x - SHIFT }, index);
        break;
      case 'MOVE_RIGHT':
        onMoveRequest({ x: x + SHIFT }, index);
        break;
      case 'MOVE_UP':
        onMoveRequest({ y: y - SHIFT }, index);
        break;
      case 'MOVE_DOWN':
        onMoveRequest({ y: y + SHIFT }, index);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown action');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Shortcuts shortcutMap={shortcutMap} mapKey="BOX" handler={handleMove} scoped>
      <div style={style}>
        {index + 1} ({x}, {y})
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleMove('MOVE_DOWN')}>
          D
        </button>
      </div>
    </Shortcuts>
  );
};
```

I cannot for the life of me work out why it is different from the keyboard event.

Comment: I've been playing with this and I am very sure this is an issue with `Shortcuts` not receiving the updated `x` and `y`. You are only sending `handleMove` to `Shortcuts` which does not accept `x` or `y` but takes it from props. Try to pass 'x' and 'y' to `Shortcuts` and then call the shortcut action with that new `x` and `y` - `handleMove = (action, newX, newY) => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok your issue:

You initialize the keyboard shortcuts in the `Shortcut` component on "didMount". That means it only registers the handler function when it mounts, with the reference to the initial `y`.

To fix this pass x & y to the `Shortcuts` component then take everything from componentDidMount and add it to a new method - `initializeShortcuts => (props: Props) => {...}`.

Run this function in `componentDidMount()` & `componentWillReceiveProps() (or getDerivedState whatever` with `props` & `nextProps` respectively and it works. Also remember to unbind the shortcuts before binding them again in the latter.

Working version - https://codesandbox.io/s/wnl6v7x69w.